# On the connected sum of a surface with a torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

I am studying the classification of Surfaces, and run into the notion of connected sum. We define it in terms of triangulations. I want to show the following. Let $S$ be a triangulated surface. I want to show that $S\#T$ with $T$ the torus is combinatorially homeomorphic to attaching a handle to $S$. I am not allowed to use the classification of Surfaces, since this is what I want to prove.

So, Let $S'$ denote the complement of a combinatorial disk in $S$, Then I want to glue the boundary of $S'$ to the complement of a combinatorial disk in $T$. How is this combinatorially homeomorphic to $S$ with a handle glued in?

EDIT: Possible solution: Since $S\#S^2\cong S$, and $T$ is $S^2$ with a handle glued in, $S\#T\cong S\#(S^2\text{with handle})\cong (S\# S^2)\text{with a handle glued in}$. Is this last line correct?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because you have not given us your definition of "$S$ with a handle glued in". In some treatments, the definition literally is "$S \# T$", in which case the answer to your question would be "this is true by definition". If that's not a satisfactory answer to you, and I suspect it is not, then you need to fill your question out by telling us exactly what you mean by gluing a handle in.

Comment: We have defined gluing in a handle as follows: we choose two triangles in a triangulation which are disjoint, and remove the interiors. Then we identify the resulting edges

Comment: Then I am wondering, are the following operations equivalent: $S\#(S^2\text{with one handle glued in })$ and $(S\#S^2)$ with a handle glued in

Comment: Does this follow from the disk theorem?

Comment: There's a problem in that you still have not said carefully enough what you mean by "we identify the resulting edges". If you do not do this very carefully, there are a lot of other possible results. For example, instead of getting $S\#$
(torus) you can also get $S\#$(Klein bottle) (this corrects an error in the previous version of this comment). You should add to the question itself (not using a comment) exactly what you mean by gluing in a handle.